# How to get an html element by tagtype in autoit

Tags: autoit

In an autoit script I'm looping through all elements with

```
For $oElement in $oFormElements
```

and I can identify an element by it's html type attribute. i.e.:

```
<input type="password .... />
```

equals:

```
If $oElement.Type = 'password' Then
```

So far so god, but can I select an HTML object not by it's type attribute but instead by it's tag type i.e. "button"

```
<button id="Test>Test</>
```

I can't find a reference in the autoit wiki that tells me what properties a DOM object can have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [_IETagNameGetCollection](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IETagNameGetCollection.htm)

```
#include <IE.au3>
Local $oIE = _IECreate("https://google.com")
Local $oButtons = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "button")
For $oButton In $oButtons
    Consolewrite("name: " & $oButton.name & " value: " & $oButton.value & @CRLF)
Next
```